# Scene Transition not working anymore after having change ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the way I navigate between different ViewControllers:

```
let newViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController3")
UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with the following extension:

```
extension UIApplication {
class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(base: presented)
    }
    return base
}
```

}

And here is the way I invoke scene transitions in my SKScene (several):

```
let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 2)
let nextScene = NewScene(size: scene!.size)
nextScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
```

Everything work fine before switching ViewControllers. Once the switching has been succeeded, I can not invoke transition anymore in my SKScene, the app get frozen without any error from Xcode (iPad connected to the Mac with live debugging)

Do you know what happens ?

I use Swift 3 and SpriteKit with ViewControllers to be able to use Vuforia static lib in a direct ViewController scene (UIView).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution, it's necessary to dismiss the actual ViewController before changing with the new one:

```
    self.dismiss(animated: false)

    let newViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController2")
    UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If the dismiss call is not done, it's not possible to do new transition scene in the new ViewController.